# gitosis-plugin integration with redmine on amazon ec2

Tags: redmine, gitosis

I am trying to integrate gitosis-plugin with redmine. I used http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way to install gitosis on the server. The gitosis works fine and I was able to use the created repositories for projects inside redmine.

As for installing gitosis-plugin I followed http://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_gitosis. I can still ssh to the server, and in the "My account" tab I can add public_keys, but when I try to create a new project I receive an error to contact the redmine admin. I looked at the production-log for redmine, and this was the error for creating a new project:

> Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - /tmp/redmine-gitosis-1329706601/gitosis/gitosis.conf):

I looked in the folder and realized the files were not created. None of the solutions helped me so far. has anyone else faced this problem, or found a solution?